# Decoding a List<int> in Dart with Redstone Mapper

Tags: json, serialization, dart, redstone.dart

I am trying to decode a list of integers, e.g. "[1,2,3,4]", like this

```
decodeJson(json, new List<int>().runtimeType)
```

but I am getting this error

```
MapperException:  UnsupportedType: List<int>. This type wasn't mapped by redstone_mapper's
transformer. See http://goo.gl/YYMou2 for more information.
```

Here is my `pubspec.yaml`

```
name: restonetest
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  angular: any
  appengine: any
  browser: any
  di: any
  fp: any
  redstone: any
  redstone_mapper: any
  shelf_static: any
transformers:
- redstone_mapper
- angular:
    html_files:
    - lib/client/models/evento/evento.html
```

What should I do?

**Edit**

The actual problem appears to be with `redstone_mapper` transformer. If I take it out from the `pubspec.yaml` then it works.

Comment: Please add the full code. And give us some information about the versions you use.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
import 'package:redstone_mapper/mapper.dart';
import 'package:redstone_mapper/mapper_factory.dart';

main() {
  bootstrapMapper();

  String json = "[1,2,3,4]";

  var x = decodeJson(json, new List<int>().runtimeType);
  print(x);
}
```

and prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Are you using the `redstone_mapper` transformer?

Comment: I don't know what that is. Please post a full example, as I requested above already.

Comment: The code is still missing... And also the versions you use of the packages and Dart SDK, ...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @luizmineo for his answer [here](https://github.com/luizmineo/redstone_mapper/issues/7#issuecomment-66842199) at the Redstone Mapper's Github repository. Apparently you can just give the *specific* type of the list because

> If the json object is an array, the decode will produce a List
>   automatically

This line of code that appears next will work for the cased exposed in the question

```
decodeJson(json, int);
```

The trick works for any type in general.